# How do I call a javascript object's method from a razor component?

Tags: javascript, blazor, razor-components

I'm working on my first Blazor project and have some difficulties to integrate and start this [gaze detection](https://webgazer.cs.brown.edu/) from one of the pages of my **blazor server app**. The gaze detection website states, that after integrating the webgazer javascript file in your website, you can start the webgazer by calling **webgazer.begin()**. I tried a lot, but still can't manage to make it work.

Here is what I trid so far:

I placed the **webgazer.js** in a folder called "js" in "wwwroot" and added the script tag in _Hosts.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@namespace CalculatorWebApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/webgazer.js"></script>
```

On the razor component called "Calibration" I want to start the webgazer, when a button is clicked. Therefore, I tried something like this:

```
@page "/Calibration"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Calibration</h1>


<p>
    <button @onclick="TriggerWebgazer">Start WebGazer</button>
</p>

@code {


    private async Task TriggerWebgazer()

    {
        await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "~/js/webgazer.js");

        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("webgazer.begin()");
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() => await this.DisposeAsync();

}
```

But then I get these errors:

```
blazor.server.js:1 [2022-12-07T00:25:09.239Z] Error: There was an error applying batch 2.
log @ blazor.server.js:1

blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
    at H (blazor.server.js:1:17228)
    at blazor.server.js:1:20455
    at ie.updateComponent (blazor.server.js:1:20480)
    at blazor.server.js:1:115262
    at Pn.processBatch (blazor.server.js:1:115634)
    at kt.<anonymous> (blazor.server.js:1:129816)
    at blazor.server.js:1:72077
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at kt._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js:1:72063)
    at kt._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:70105)
blazor.server.js:1 [2022-12-07T00:25:09.383Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild'))
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

What am I doing wrong? Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't load it in a `script` tag and then try to `import` it later - also, drop the `()` - just invoke `"webgazer.begin"`

Comment: This indeed solved the problem - thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your script before `blazor.server.js` as follows:

```
<script src="~/js/webgazer.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Please try this `<button @onclick="(() => TriggerWebgazer())">`

Comment: And also try `<script src="js/webgazer.js"></script>`

Comment: Another thing that you can try is add the reference to _layout.cshtml instead of _Host.cshtml